# "OK Google, Shazam this song" not working

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, moto-x, shazam

I'm using 2014 Moto X (2nd Gen) with Android 5.1 and latest version of Shazam application (5.10.1-150928) from Google Play Store.

I'm trying out the following feature and cannot get it to work:

["OK Google, Shazam this song" – Shazam Help](https://support.shazam.com/hc/en-us/articles/205024298--Ok-Google-Shazam-this-song-)

My phone recognizes me saying "*OK Moto X*" and "*OK Google*" without any issues.

Comment: Just a suggestion- but Google search does music searching without using Shazam. "Ok Google, whats this song?". I haven't tested, but this same phrase might work to at least pop-up an "open default application" box where you can pick Shazam.

Comment: Things to do: _Make sure you have the Shazam app fully installed and try again._ & _Ensure Shazam and the Google app are updated and Shazam away._ and importantly _Where can you use it?_  It works only in _US, UK, AU, CA_. What other thing to try, “Ok Google, shazam this song”

“Ok Google, shazam this track”

“Ok Google, shazam this tune”

“Ok Google, recognize this song on Shazam”

“Ok Google, recognize this track on Shazam”

“Ok Google, recognize this tune on Shazam”

“Ok Google, shazam this song on Shazam”

“Ok Google, open Shazam”

“Ok Google, launch Shazam”

Comment: @paulmz, while Google offers similar functionality to Shazam, the question is in regards to `Shazam` and not `Google` (or workaround).

Comment: @Lucky app _IS_ installed and I _AM_ in U.S. _AND_, I am saying one of hot words such as: `OK Google, Shazam this song`.

Comment: Okay I mentioned the other ways too :). But the command you say should work. I don't know why it's not working. Try updating the Google app. Alao note that Google voice command should recognize the word "Shazam". So make sure the app picks up your command exactly as you say. Sorry I couldn't try that out since I'm not in one of those supported countries. ;)